# Shell command for opening "Control Panel/Personalization/Start/Choose which folders appear on start" in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shell, control-panel

Also, if there is some way to see this shell command from Task Manager, Process Explorer, or some other useful utility when that window is open, Please also explain how and what to look at/for so I may find the shell commands for other more obscure settings locations. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question. What have you tried? What are you trying to achieve? There are multiple things in the title and the body, and it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

We can only open this level -> **Start**, but not on the certain settings as "Choose which folders appear on start".

Please open **Run**, and type this command:

***ms-settings:personalization-start***